# IntelliJ Database Tools plugin cannot identify symbols of system stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, intellij-idea

I encountered the problem while learning dynamic sql and the `sp_sqlexecute` command.

```sql
declare @stmt nvarchar(100) = N'select @v1 + @v2';
declare @params nvarchar(100) = N'@v1 int, @v2 int';
exec sp_executesql @stmt, @params, @v1 = 1, @v2 = 2;
```

In the IntelliJ IDE, the `sp_executesql` part is marked as "unknown database function", despite that these statements actually execute well.

[image]

Other system stored procedures behave similarly.

Any idea how to tell the IDE where to find these system stored procedures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the context database or you can use "sys." to work in any context.

Try this:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(100) = N'select @v1 + @v2';
declare @params nvarchar(100) = N'@v1 int, @v2 int';
exec sys.sp_execute_sql @stmt, @params, @v1 = 1, @v2 = 2;
```